# FlipView micro-freeze when flipping page Windows-RT

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, flipview

I'm developing a C# metro app where I use a ScrollViewer inside a FlipView to flip through some high definition images `(2400x1800)`. It works fine in the simulator, but when deploying to a Surface RT there are some performance issues. When flipping through the FlipView for the first time the UI freezes noticeably every time a new image is presented.

I have even tried to pre-load all images into BitmapImages when starting the app. But the micro-freezes are still there the first time you go through the FlipView.

I also tried to turn on `DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter`, and it seems like the Memory flag doesn't increase when creating the BitmapImages, but it increases when flipping through the FlipView the first time which leads me to believe they aren't really loaded even though they are created and their source is set?

[Here is an example project where you can see the issue](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=67EB5EE74F5D6713!167)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The FlipView or ScrollViewer is likely virtualizing the contents. Try to change the ItemsPanel to a StackPanel. This will load all of the images into memory at once though (uncompressed, no less), so be wary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried to change the ItemsPanel to a StackPanel and the micro freezes are gone. However this isn't a viable solution for me since I will have 100+ images in the FlipView. I have also tried to use a StackPanel and do loading/unloading of images on the SelectionChanged event, but this results in the same freezes as when using virtualization.

Comment: You can try changing the Virtualization mode of the VirtualizingStackPanel. You can also load the images asynchronously. I believe the VirtualizingStackPanel has methods that you can use for when the item is created. What I would do is either create a Model that stores your images and loads them asynchronously when it is constructed or have a ViewModel which does something similar. If you do the Model method, it will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (or extend ObjectModel if you're using MvvmLight) so that it can warn the View when it is done loading.

Comment: I tried to change the Virtualization mode of the VirtualizingStackPanel to Recycling but it didn't affect the freezes. I'm not sure I understand your other suggestion. But I have tried to load all my BitmapImages when starting the app. I also tried to load them in a background task when the BitmapImage get property is called (calling OnPropertyChanged when done). But It seems like it's when the UIElement that uses the BitmapImage is created by the ItemsPanel that the freeze occurs, so neither of the things worked. Or are you saying I can load the UIElements asynchronously somehow?

Comment: So add a Loaded event to your `UIElements` (likely to the Image object itself inside of your `DataTemplate`). Then, in this `Loaded` event, you need to find what the image is supposed to be (what its `Uri` is). The most likely place to find this is the `DataContext` of the `Image` (likely your `Model`). Then, using this `DataContext`, asynchronously get the bits of the `Image` itself, either from disk or downloaded. Then, when those bits are ready, set the source of the Image to the bits (which should already be in memory at this point).

Comment: Did you solve somehow this issue? I have the same proble. Thank you.